# How to track outbound links in Google Analytics according to this method, incl. Label & Non-Interaction?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, dom-events

I came across [this helpful](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en) article from Google Support regarding tracking Outbound links, but it leaves a bit to be desired in that it does not include instructions regarding event labels or the non-interaction setting

What I'd like to know is how to properly modify this code to allow for that

... And I quote:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function trackOutboundLink(link, category, action) {

try {
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category , action]);
} catch(err){}

setTimeout(function() {
document.location.href = link.href;
}, 100);
}
</script>
```

> Next, revise outbound links to call the new function without first
>   following the link. For example, to log every click on a particular
>   link to www.example.com, you would use the _trackEvent() method in the
>   link's  tag:

`<a href="http://www.example.com" onClick="trackOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Links', 'example.com'); return false;">`

(end quote)

EDIT: I haven't gotten an answer on this one yet, so I'll make an attempt here and perhaps some comments or answers will come based on my attempt

What I'm not clear on is how to actually enter this code to work properly since this is different from a standard onClick event instructions and involve a separate script

For instance, do I literally put 'category, action, label' in the `trackOutboundLink` function and the `_gaq.push` section, or do I put the actual values for my link each time? I don't think I am supposed to put the particulars for each link on each page am I?

Here's my attempt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function trackOutboundLink(link, category, action, label, value, non-interaction) {

try {
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category , action, label, value, non-interaction]);
} catch(err){}

setTimeout(function() {
document.location.href = link.href;
}, 100);
}
</script>
```

And my link would be:

`<a href="http://www.example.com" onClick="trackOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Links', 'example.com',,,true); return false;">`

Finally, what is the significance of 'this' in the OnClick event?

Comment: I tried this as well on my website and I noticed that very few outbound link clicks are recorded, perhaps because the 100ms in some cases isn't enough time for the trackEvent code to execute and send the request. I do get some recorded though. I did something similar to that code as well.

Comment: At this point in time the proper way would be to implement Google Analytics via the Google Tag Manager and use the Link Click Event Listener Tag (which will take care of timeouts etc, without you having to write any Javascript at all). Other than that see Crayon Violents answer.

Comment: Hi @EikePierstorff , do you have a link about how to use GTM in this manner? Or would you want to supply a full answer including instructions?

Comment: If you have a little experience with the tag manager the following documentation is actually quite good:
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/3420054?hl=en&ref_topic=3002579

If you need instructions from the start (setting up an GTM account etc.) then holler away and I'll do a detailled writeup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your actual question here is, other than what the syntax for all of the `_trackEvent` arguments are.. The link you posted is an example of how to implement outbound link tracking, so it doesn't focus on the actual `_trackEvent` syntax.  Here is a link to the document entry for `_trackEvent` itself:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Comment: Hi, the question is how to modify the above code to also collect event labels and supply a non-interaction setting

Comment: @Drewdavid it involves passing more arguments to your wrapper function and adding them to the `_gaq.push()` call.. did you actually read the link I supplied?